# android: mkdirs() returns false

Tags: java, android, io

Can someone tell me, why my app can't create dirs?
Here is my Code:

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "meinordner");
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            boolean s = dir.mkdirs();
            if(!s) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("could not create dir");
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

when i execute the app, the alert is shown. I even tried to start the app when my phone is not connected to the computer and therfore the storage is not mounted somewhere else

Comment: What are your target and min sdk versions?

Comment: WRITE includes READ, but the answer beneath helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Second, change:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + "meinordner");
```

to:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "meinordner");
```